# Manipulate CSV file: increment cell coordinates/position

Tags: excel, csv, auto-increment

I have a csv file with one entry on each line, three entries form a whole dataset. So what I need to do now, is to put these sets in the columns in one row. I have difficutlies to describe the problem (thus my search was not giving me a solution), so here's an example.
Sample CSV file:

```
1  Joe  
2  Doe  
3  7/7/1990  
4  Jane  
5  Done  
6  6/6/2000
```

What I want in the end is this:

```
1  Name  Surname  Birthdate  
2  Joe   Doe      7/7/1990  
3  Jane  Done     6/6/2000
```

I'm trying to find a solution to make this automatically, as my actual file consists of 480 datasets, each set containing 16 entries, and it would take me days to do it manually.

I was able to fill the first line with Excel's indirect function:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN()-COLUMN($A1))
```

As COLUMN returns the column number, if I drag the first line down in Excel, obviously this shows exactly the same as the first line:

```
1  Name  Surname  Birthdate  
2  Joe   Doe      7/7/1990  
3  Joe   Doe      7/7/1990
```

Now I'm looking for a way to increment the cell position by one:

```
   A           B      C       D
1 Joe        =A1   =B1+1   =C1+1
2 Doe        =D1+1
3 7/7/1990
4 Jane
```

What should lead to:

```
   A           B    C     D  
1 Joe        =A1   =A2   =A3  
2 Doe        =A4   =A5   =A4  
3 7/7/1990  
4 Jane
```

As you can see in the example given, the cell coordinates for A increment by one, and I have no idea how to do this automatically in Excel. I think there must be a better way than using nested Excel function, as the task (increment +1) seems actually pretty easy.
I'm also open to solutions involving sed, awk (of which I only have a very superficial knowledge) or other command line tools.
You're help is appreciated very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'BEGIN { y=1; printf "Name Surname Birthdate\n%s",y; x=1;}
  {if (x == 3) {
   y = y + 1;
   printf "%s\n%s",$2,y;
   x=1;
  }
  else {
   printf " %s ",$2;
   x = x + 1;
  }}' input_file.txt
```

This may work for what you want to do.  Your sample does not include the commas, so I'm not sure if they are really in there or not. If they are, you will need to modify the code slightly with the -F, flag so that it treats them as such.

This second code snippet will provide the output with a comma delimiter.  Again, it is assuming that your sample input file did not have commas to delimit the 1 Joe and 2 Doe.

```
awk 'BEGIN { y=1; printf "Name Surname Birthdate\n%s",y; x=1;}
 {if (x == 3) {
  y = y + 1;
  printf "%s\n%s,",$2,y;
  x=1;
 }
  else {
  printf " %s,",$2;
  x = x + 1;
 }}' input_file.txt
```

Both of the awk scripts will set x and y variables to one, where the y variable will increment your line numbering.  The x variable will count up to 3 and then reset itself back to one.  This is so that it prints each line in a row, until it gets to the 3rd item where it will then insert a newline character.

There are easier/more complex ways to do this with regexes and a language like perl, but since you mentioned awk, I believe this will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the script, but it's output is not quiet what I expected. It puts "Name Surname Birthdate" on first line, 1 on second line, 2 on third line and 3 on fourth line. Second code snippet puts 1 , , on second line, 2 , , , on third line and 3, on fourth line. Got an idea?

Comment: In your file snippets I didn't see that there are any actual comma delimiters, but they are just spaces.  If there are actual comma delimiters in your files, then at the very beginning of the awk statement you can add a -F"," flag which tells the script to use commas as delimiters.  That might explain why you are seeing what you are seeing.  So try it with awk -F"," '{BEGIN... and see if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for you're help - I didn't manage to make the script run as desired, even with -F. But in consequence, to print value z of line 1, what would the command be? After that, I'll leave you alone and learn awk from beginning :-)